# c# - Find node value without root element

Tags: c#, xml

This is my column value in sql:

```
<ProductId>101</ProductId>
<ProductName>TShirt</ProductName>
<Description>UCB</Description>
<Category>199</Category>
<Weight>150</Weight>
<Price>2500</Price>
<images></images>
```

Sometimes it looks like this also:

```
<ProductId xsi:nil="true" ></ProductId> 
<ProductName>Toys</ProductName>
<Description xsi:nil="true" ></Description>
<Category xsi:nil="true" ></Category>
<Weight xsi:nil="true" ></Weight>
<Price xsi:nil="true" ></Price>
<images></images>
```

I want to extract 'ProductName' value i.e. TShirt from this column. It could be any node,  How do I do this?

This is my c# code

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlString);

string fieldValue = xml.Element(fieldToSearch).ToString();
```

But since it is not proper xml string it gives error so I wrote explicitly

```
string xmlString = "<root>" + columnValue + "</root>";
```

What is the correct way to find the node value?

Edit: The value can be extrtacted for Weight/Description/Price, any node. The error comes when xsi:nil is found.

Comment: Any way you can change how data gets stored in SQL? what you did might be a-okay but storing invalid xml is a bit meh imo

Comment: I would wrap the xml in a root node similar to how you are doing it, maybe not by string concatenation, but that should work. What is the problem?

Comment: The error is due to innertext being null.   Try following : string fieldValue = (string)xml.Element(fieldToSearch;  ToString() will fail when null.

Comment: `It could be any node` that means your `TShirt` value present on any column? or in `<ProductName>`

Comment: @jdweng `ToString()` will fail if the *element* is null, which will only happen if it's missing. If the *value* is null or empty, there's no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error because the `xsi:nil` attribute has a namespace prefix of `xsi`. As you're missing the parent element, there's no declaration of this prefix.

Ideally, you'd fix the source of this so that you store well formed XML rather than a bunch of child elements, but if you're stuck with it then the easiest way to get around the issue is to add the namespace declaration to your dummy `root` element:

```cs
var xmlString = 
    "<root xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" + 
    columnValue + 
    "</root>";
```

Secondly, I'd note that `ToString()` will return the element itself, e.g. `<ProductName>Toys</ProductName>`. If you just want the value, then you can use the explicit conversion:

```cs
var fieldValue = (string) xml.Element(fieldToSearch);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pioo3b) for a working demo.